# Issue with object not serializable class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable Error

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to Load huge amount of data from Spark to HBase. I am using saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset method.

I am creating ImmutableWritable and Put and saving that is required as below.

```
 dataframe.mapPartitions { rows =>
      {
        rows.map { eachRow =>
          {
            val rowKey = Seq(eachRow.getAs[String]("uniqueId"), eachRow.getAs[String]("authTime")).mkString(",")
            val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
            val fields = eachRow.schema.fields;

            for (i <- 0 until fields.length) {
              put.addColumn(userCF, Bytes.toBytes(fields(i).name), Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(eachRow.get(i))))
            }

            (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey)), put)
          }
        }
      }
    }.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration)
```

My data is 30GB worth and it is present in HDFS in 60 files.

When i submit the same job with 10 files at a time, every thing went fine.

But, when i submit every thing at once, it is giving this error. The error is really frustrating and i tried every thing within possibility. But really wondering what made it to run successfully when the data is of 5GB and what made it to result in error when it is 30GB.

Has any one faced this kind of issues.?

Comment: Can you put complete stack trace here...?

Comment: When i allocated 40G memory per executor the job is getting close, but whenever i allocated less memory i am facing this error. It means, whenever there is a shuffle i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because ImmutableBytesWritable is not serializable. When there is a shuffle, apache spark tries to serialize it to send to another node. The same would happen if you'd try to take some or collect it on driver.

There only two approaches, actually.

- Do not use it if you're shuffling. If you just need to put each record from disk into a database, then looks like shuffling is not required. Make sure it is. If you need to preprocess your data before they go to database, keep it in some other serializable format and convert to the required only, when you saving it.
- Use another serializer. Apache spark comes with Kryo (make sure you're using spark 2.0.0 - Kryo has been updated there and it fixes few nasty concurrency bugs). In order to use it, you have to configure it. It's not hard, but require a bit of code.

Comment: Hi evgeni. Yes  I tried kryo and simply made the class serializable by providing it in the list of classes. But kryo gave other serialization issues for me. Pricisely, index out of bounds issue. So I have no choice but drop it.. I hope new spark API got better kryo API.

Comment: @Srini, what spark version do you use? If before 2.0.0, then Kryo has an issue you cannot workaround. That might be it.